Error with Azure Functions in Python: "WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found" and "Value cannot be null (Parameter 'provider') with python 3.11.9
I'm trying to set up an Azure Function in Python, but I'm encountering errors when running the function. Below is my function code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="APIPreguntaleia")
def APIPreguntaleia(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

When I run the function, I get the following console error:
Executing task: .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt 

Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in r:\fast-api\.venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.19.0)
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start 

Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-05-30T19:29:34.890Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '95a1dbe5-8264-4a29-b39a-5a6dc58447df'.
[2024-05-30T19:29:34.893Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found.
[2024-05-30T19:29:34.903Z] Failed to stop host instance '96a67c8f-f7a7-45fa-83c3-be938325ae8c'.
[2024-05-30T19:29:34.907Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
[2024-05-30T19:29:34.915Z] Host startup operation has been canceled

 *  The terminal process "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 


I tried installing the azure-functions-worker package, but encountered another error:
PS R:\Fast-API> pip install azure-functions-worker
Collecting azure-functions-worker
  Using cached azure_functions_worker-1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.7 kB)
Collecting grpcio~=1.33.1 (from azure-functions-worker)
  Using cached grpcio-1.33.2.tar.gz (20.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting grpcio-tools~=1.33.1 (from azure-functions-worker)
  Using cached grpcio-tools-1.33.2.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from grpcio~=1.33.1->azure-functions-worker)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting protobuf<4.0dev,>=3.5.0.post1 (from grpcio-tools~=1.33.1->azure-functions-worker)
  Using cached protobuf-3.20.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (720 bytes)
Using cached azure_functions_worker-1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Using cached protobuf-3.20.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio, grpcio-tools
  Building wheel for grpcio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for grpcio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      ...
      error: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for grpcio-tools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [69 lines of output]
      ...
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(394): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio-tools
Failed to build grpcio grpcio-tools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for grpcio, grpcio-tools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Environment details:
Python version: 3.11.9
Azure Functions Core Tools version: 4.0.5801
I've tried several solutions but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this issue?
Thanks for the help.

Is your issue resolved? Check if the below provided solution helps.

Uninstall Python and download it from python.org MSI and install again.
Create a new folder and create the function project in it.
Follow below steps:
mkdir <foldername>
cd <foldername>


Use below commands to create the function project:

func init --worker-runtime python --model v2
func new


Create a virtual environment:

py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate


Include the required packages to install in reqirements.txt:

azure-functions
//other required packages


Run the command to install the packages:

pip install -r requirements.txt

I have created a function project and used your code:
import datetime
import json
import logging

import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="APIPreguntaleia")
def APIPreguntaleia(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

Console Output:
C:\Users\uname\pyfunc1>func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-05-31T05:54:27.183Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        APIPreguntaleia:  http://localhost:7071/api/APIPreguntaleia

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-31T05:54:31.822Z] Executing 'Functions.APIPreguntaleia' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=736cdd82-c6c1-4e47-974b-d6365eba2b06)
[2024-05-31T05:54:31.893Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-05-31T05:54:31.991Z] Executed 'Functions.APIPreguntaleia' (Succeeded, Id=736cdd82-c6c1-4e47-974b-d6365eba2b06, Duration=195ms)
[2024-05-31T05:54:32.608Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-05-31T05:54:41.629Z] Executing 'Functions.APIPreguntaleia' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=0d7b7b8f-b150-452d-8d51-b20ca8e4a6c5)
[2024-05-31T05:54:41.642Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-05-31T05:54:41.644Z] Executed 'Functions.APIPreguntaleia' (Succeeded, Id=0d7b7b8f-b150-452d-8d51-b20ca8e4a6c5, Duration=19ms)


